# No output from property setter when appending instance to list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was just experimenting with the property decorators when I figured out that a print statement from within a property setter would **not always** do its job, all other conditions equal. In the below example, I am getting the expected output from the directly initialized class instance (the `fiver` section), but not when appending instances to a list (the `objlist` section).
Python 3.5.3

```
class Celsius:
    def __init__(self,temperature=0):
        self._temperature=temperature
    
    @property
    def temperature(self):
        print("Getting value...")
        return self._temperature
    @temperature.setter
    def temperature(self, value):
        print("Guess, you know what you're doing...")
        if value < -273:
            print ("Impossible temperature...")
            self._temperature = -273
        else:
            self._temperature = value        

objlist=[]
objlist.append(Celsius(4))
objlist.append(Celsius(-499))

fiver=Celsius(5)
print (fiver.temperature)
fiver.temperature=-408
print (fiver.temperature)
```

Comment: Your `__init__` method is setting the internal attribute `self._temperature`, it's not accessing the property/descriptor `self.temperature` at all

Comment: @IainShelvington I see. What I need, is for the code ```objlist.append(Celsius(-499))``` to actually invoke the self.temperature (for error control and debugging reasons). Should I then explicitly call the setter from ```__init__ ``` or there is a more elegant way to do that? Thanks.

Comment: @Tomerikoo That's useful, thanks.

Comment: @Tomerikoo Ah, sure! Thanks, that wasn't obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `__init__` you set the *"internal"* value `_temperature` directly. This ***doesn't*** call the `setter`, as the `property.setter` is defined over `temperature`.

If you want the `__init__` to pass through the `setter` validation as well, funny as it sounds, just use the `setter`:

```py
def __init__(self,temperature=0):
    self.temperature = temperature
```

Comment: Yes, I must have forgotten that the single leading underscore is just a convention - so, was expecting the '@property' decorator to have some magic capability to recognize a "private" class variable. Not the case.

Comment: @vanhemt it is *partly* private. The only point is that the `property` "wraps" that attribute with a new name. That's why the `_` convention is usually used. You indicate that the attribute itself is somewhat private, and the outside world can still access it, but through the wrapping `property`